Changing background of Shopify section - ID's reliable?
I'm trying to change the background colour of a section generated by an app, but it seems the only way to do it is via the section's ID, ie:
#shopify-section-template--18331524890870__1723807728af0eaf1c {
    background-color: gray;
}

However I believe I have read these generated ID's are not completely reliable and subject to change?
Is there a more reliable method to do this?

check this. and you can use wild card. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475702/turning-a-dynamic-css-selector-to-a-static-one

@NINE Thanks, but that would end up targeting all elements that start with #shopify-section-template--.

Shouldn't you first check to see if the ID does change before looking for other solutions. Otherwise, you are limited to Javascript.

@Paulie_D From what I have read online, the ID shouldn't be relied on.

Trust the evidence of your own test before the internet

@Paulie_D How? Wait until the ID changes and the site breaks? https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/why-does-my-section-id-keep-changing-in-shopify/td-p/2406235
